# Getting time taken for the edge using GraphHopper map matching

Tags: maps, graph, map-matching, graphhopper

Here is the GPX data I am giving to GraphHopper Map matching library:

```
private List<GPXEntry> getList()
{
    List<GPXEntry> sampleEntries = new ArrayList<GPXEntry>();
    GPXEntry point1 = new GPXEntry(13.0009316,77.5947316, 1431849367077L);
    GPXEntry point2 = new GPXEntry(12.9868999,77.6042,1431849683112L);
    GPXEntry point3 = new GPXEntry(12.9867766,77.6043633,1431849718336L);
    GPXEntry point4 = new GPXEntry(12.98658,77.6043283,1431849752169L);
    GPXEntry point5 = new GPXEntry(12.9846133,77.6052366,1431850069237L);
    sampleEntries.add(point1);
    sampleEntries.add(point2);
    sampleEntries.add(point3);
    sampleEntries.add(point4);
    sampleEntries.add(point5);
    return sampleEntries;
}
```

It is list of `GPXEntry` objects each containing lat, long and the timestamp of vehicle when the location was recorded.

Now, with map library, I am able to get edges and path using Dijkstra's algorithm. 
The `QueryResults` object has the following:

```
for (QueryResult item : queryResult) {
        System.out.println("Snapped position: "+ item.getSnappedPoint());
        edgesMap.put(item.getClosestEdge().getEdge(), item.getQueryDistance());
    }
```

I am getting edge ID and in the end the distance calculated is also correct when I compare with GoogleMaps distance. But, I want to use the timeStamp(epoch) data which I have given in the GPX data. I am assuming the library creates edges based on location points I have given and snaps it to actual route referred by OSM file.

I want to know for each edgeID, how do I get the time taken? For e.g., time between `point1` and `point2` should be `(1431849683112L-1431849367077L)`.
 Does the library provide anything for this or I need to do it separately.

Comment: have you solved this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the associated time indirectly for every edge via the EdgeMatch class using the distance and speed for every linked edgeState.

BTW: you are probably doing the map matching not correct. Although the QueryGraph does a similar thing and e.g. we are using this under the hood in the map matching component, this alone won't work that good for many points. Please have a look into the [Java part](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching#java-usage) of the map matching library

Comment: That code doesn't work at this particular line: `LocationIndexMatch locationIndex = new LocationIndexMatch(graph, new RAMDirectory());`   It says: The constructor `LocationIndexMatch(GraphStorage, RAMDirectory)` is undefined.<br> I also tried with `LocationIndexMatch locationIndex = new LocationIndexMatch(graph, new LocationIndexTree(hopper.getGraph(), new RAMDirectory()));`. It says `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Comment: now fixed in the readme